# Convert key value pair string to HashMap in one line

Tags: string, parsing, rust, split, hashmap

I have a string with contents like the following:

```
key1:value1 key2:value2 key3:value3 ...
```

I want to end up with a `HashMap<&str, &str>` (or equivalent), which maps the keys and values from the string (e.g. a hash lookup of "key1" should return "value1").

Currently, I am able to easily fill up the HashMap with the following:

```rust
let mut hm = HashMap::new();
for item in my_string.split_ascii_whitespace() {
    let splits = item.split(":").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    hm.insert(splits[0], splits[1]);
}
```

However, what if I wanted to do it in one line (even at cost of readability, for "code golf"-ish purposes)? I know how to do this with a `HashSet`, so I'd imagine it would look somewhat similar; perhaps something like this (which doesn't actually compile):

```rust
let hm: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::from_iter(my_string.split_ascii_whitespace().map(|s| s.split(":").take(2).collect::<Vec<&str>>()));
```

I have tried different combinations of things similar to the above, but I can't seem to find something that will actually compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach toward solving this problem was remembering that an `Iterator<Item=(K, V)>` can be collected into an `HashMap<K, V>` so upon knowing that I worked backwards to try to figure out how I could turn a `&str` into an `Iterator<Item=(&str, &str)>` which I managed to do using the String [`find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.find) and [`split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_at) methods:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn one_liner(string: &str) -> HashMap<&str, &str> {
    string.split_whitespace().map(|s| s.split_at(s.find(":").unwrap())).map(|(key, val)| (key, &val[1..])).collect()
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(one_liner("key1:value1 key2:value2 key3:value3"));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=43f5f4565d37fdb7d79bcddbf1b758c9)

The second `map` call was necessary to remove the leading `:` character from the value string.

Comment: I see, `split` just returns an iterator while `split_at` returns exactly two slices. Looks like this may just do it! Thanks